# How to use npm start on remote dev box with create-react-app

Tags: create-react-app

I would like to know how to use the create-react-app "npm start" script when development takes place on a remote host.

Nginx is running as a reverse proxy. The external uri looks like:

```
https://my-dev-box/my-cra
```

which is set to proxy to:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

The CRA app is static (ie no API calls).

The errors appearing in the browser's web dev console are 404s related to /static/js/bundle.js and favicon. The app's index.html page is served with a 200 response.

When I build the app, "npm build" produces an index.html file with the correct paths (courtesy of the "homepage" setting in package.json). I have looked at the documentation/tickets surrounding "Invalid Host Header" and "DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK" but have not found a combo which works for me.

It appears to me that the fundamental issue is that "npm start" does not seem aware (as "npm build" is aware) that the WebDevServer is behind a proxy and is thus not constructing correct paths for resources.

So to restate the question, does anyone know how to get "npm start" working nicely behind a reverse proxy on remote development box. (create-react-app version used: 1.5.2)

(Note: application works perfectly behind proxy when using "npm build".)

Update: Courtesy of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050851/create-react-app-change-src-of-bundle-js-in-development?rq=1) I found this comment in "webpack.config.dev.js":

```
// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
const publicPath = '/';
```

which I guess means that what I want to do is not going to be that practical unless I eject the project. (Which I'm a little reluctant to do - the reason for using create-react-app is newness to React.)